# Measurement in edit mode

Tags: measurement

I downloaded a vehicle from a source that I forgotten. When I enter into edit mode, the face selected show a lot of measurements which made the view very messy. Please see photo 1 and photo 2. Would anybody teach me how to remove those measurement. Thank you.

LightmanLeaf

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Viewport Overlays*, disable the *Measurement* options:

[image]